# How to get a double column verbatim in a single column table, in a double column document?

Tags: floats, positioning, two-column, sourcecode

I have a double column document in which I need to place two source code listings side by side. Naturally a two column document's single column is too narrow so the two listings need to span the page width.

`\onecolum` `\twocolumn` isn't an option because these need to be in the middle of a document and space is a premium.

I've tried several options of `figure*`, `table*` but can't get my head around how to get it to display properly.

In a single column document it was simple enough as I used `{multicols}{2}` and then used `lstlisting` to display the code, but switching to two column as expected, places the two columns in a single document column.

Any ideas on how to go about this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's one possible solution using the twocolumn class option and `figure*` and two `minipage`s to typeset the listings (since `figure*` was used, the listings will appear on the top of the next page):

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-6]
\begin{figure*}
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
\begin{lstlisting}
if (i<=0) then i := 1;
if (i>=0) then i := 0;
if (i<>0) then i := 0;
\end{lstlisting}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
\begin{lstlisting}
if (i<=0) then i := 1;
if (i>=0) then i := 0;
\end{lstlisting}
\end{minipage}%
\caption{Two  side-by-side listings}
\label{fig:listings}
\end{figure*}
\lipsum[1-6]

\end{document}
```

[image]

And here's now another option: instead of using the `twocolumn` document option, the `multicol` package is used to produce the text in two-column mode; the `multicols` environment is ended, the side-by-side listings are typeset using simple `minipage`s (the `caption` package was used to produce a possible caption using `\captionof`), and then another `multicols` environment begins:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\begin{multicols}{2}
\lipsum[1-2]
\end{multicols}
\noindent\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
\begin{lstlisting}
if (i<=0) then i := 1;
if (i>=0) then i := 0;
if (i<>0) then i := 0;
\end{lstlisting}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
\begin{lstlisting}
if (i<=0) then i := 1;
if (i>=0) then i := 0;
\end{lstlisting}
\end{minipage}%
\captionof{figure}{Two  side-by-side listings}
\label{fig:listings}
\end{minipage}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\lipsum[1-2]
\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

In this last option, the usual restriction of `multicol` with floats apply.

[image]

Comment: Man perfect, you are amazing, thanks a lot!